# Is it possible for a struct to have a reference to a trait object that has generic methods, without making the struct itself generic?

Tags: rust

Is it possible for a struct to have a reference to a trait object that has generic methods, without making the struct itself generic?

```
trait Foo {
    fn generic_method<T>(&self) {}
}

struct MyFoo {}
impl Foo for MyFoo {}

struct Bar<'a> {
    my_foo: &'a mut (Foo + 'a),
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(my_foo: &'a mut Foo) -> Self {
        Self { my_foo }
    }
}
```

This code gives me the error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Foo` cannot be made into an object
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     my_foo: &'a mut (Foo + 'a),
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Foo` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: method `generic_method` has generic type parameters

error[E0038]: the trait `Foo` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     fn new(my_foo: &'a mut Foo) -> Self {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Foo` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: method `generic_method` has generic type parameters
```

Comment: Relevant part of the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because all the possible instantiations of `generic_method` are not known beforehand, so there is no way that the compiler could generate a proper vtable for `generic_method`.

As you mentioned, you can make the `struct` generic instead:

```
struct Bar<'a, T: Foo + 'a> {
    my_foo: &'a mut T
}

impl<'a, T: Foo> Bar<'a, T> {
    fn new(my_foo: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        Self {my_foo}
    }
}
```